# Weird select error in python

Tags: python, sockets, python-sockets

Ok, so I have Python 2.5 and Windows XP. I was using select.select with a socket object. I tried it again and again, but whenever I run it, the thread it is in gives me an error like select.error(9, "Bad file descriptor").
The code is something like this:

```
import socket, select
s = socket.socket()
s.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), 1312))
s.listen(5)
inputs = [s]
outputs = []
while True:
    r, w, e = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)
    for sock in r:
        if sock is s:
            inputs.append(s.accept()[0])
        else:
            print s
            print s.recv(1024)
```

Any info would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You called `select.select` with no arguments. It should be something like: `select.select(inputs, outputs, [])`.
2. In the `else` you need to use `sock`, not `s` (the server).
3. Once the peer disconnects from a previously connected socket, you should remove it from the `inputs` list. You can know the peer has disconnected if `sock.recv()` returns an empty string or raises a `socket.error` exception. If you don't do this, you might end up feeding an invalid socket descriptor to `select.select`, causing the error you talked about.

Comment: Sorry, i miss typed that, in my code, **select.select(_inputs_, _outputs_, _inputs_)**. I will fix that

Comment: Cool. My other two comments still apply :)

Comment: LOL. Once again a result of my hurried code. I fixed that in the actual code. And the third comment, well, the client doesn't disconnect.